# Controlling coreless DC motor using ESP8266-01

Tags: microcontroller, dc-motor, bjt, esp8266, back-emf

I want to control a coreless 3.7 VDC motor (quadcopter motor) using a ESP8266-01 module. I've used a BC547 (BJT) to act as a switch for motor. The circuit worked fine with LEDs but when connected to motor, the ESP8266 does not even able to establish a wi-fi connection. I think the ESP8266 is resetting itself. I have added an 1N4148 as a flyback diode but still the problem exists. Is it anything to do with back EMF? If so how to reduce it? Or is there any other good option to control a coreless motor with ESP8266-01?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsfrs5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Try with two batteries to see if power is the problem. If so, there are various measures you can take: decoupling, filtering, diode + cap to bridge surges, etc.

Comment: How much current does the motor take in stall and full load situations? I bet it's more than a BC547 can supply.

Comment: _Which_ quadcopter motor? What capacity and 'C' rating (or max current rating) is the battery? Diode should be a schottky type, not 1N4148 which is only good for small signals. BC547 is only good for 100mA. Use a FET such as IRLML2502, and a good size (>=100uF) low-esr capacitor across the power supply. PWM frequency should be >=20KHz.

Comment: Hi @BruceAbbott, agree with your good suggestions on diode and FET but PWM doesn't have to be above 20.kHz. Were you recommending that for the old 'inaudible' reason? It obviously depends on the motor but, as an example,  we used 2 kHz for small brushed DC motors in office equipment as endorsed by the motor manufacturer.

Comment: the circuit works if the gate signal is initially removed and after the establishment of wifi signal..the gate pin is connected again.the circuit works just fine. Why does this happens on starting alone?

Comment: @TonyM coreless motors have much lower inductance than conventional iron-cored motors. A 716 coreless motor from a micro coax heli motor that I tested measured 20uH.

Comment: "the circuit works if the gate signal is initially removed" - what happens if you leave the 'gate' circuit on but disconnect the motor? Measure the resistance of your motor, what is it?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, thanks, interesting data to learn. What made you pick 20 kHz as a minimum? We found the old wives tale about silent above 20 kHz to be rubbish when tried on a few different motors and on solenoids, but it persists as a myth :-)

Comment: @BruceAbbott the resistance of motor is 5 ohms, if i disconnect the motor the circuit is perfectly working

Comment: @TonyM can i use 1n4007 for diode? and where can i connect the decoupling capacitor or bypass capacitor in my circuit. is it possible that this problem is due to high stalling current when the motor starts?

Comment: 5 Ohms at 3.7V is 740mA - more than the transistor can handle - combined with ESP8266's own current draw during transmission might be too much for the battery (whose specs you never bothered to tell us...).  I'm guessing the motor has about 100uH inductance, which might also be producing short voltage pikes. What happens if you replace the motor with a 5 Ohm resistor?

Comment: @TonyM 20-30KHz to reduce peak current and noise on the power supply (higher frequency is easier to filter). 20KHz may not eliminate all subharmonics, but for those of us with old ears it certainly helps.

Comment: @BruceAbbott battery specs : 3.7V , 300mAh , 20C LiPo battery but im using a small power supply module for testing. If i replace the motor with resistor , the circuits works just fine

Comment: guys, now the circuit works fine, i used a darlington pair and added 100k resistor for base. the circuit works fine for some time. but after some time, when the motor runs really fast the esp8266-01 resets itself. i think its due to motor drawing all the current and leaves only small current for esp8266. Is there any way to supply the required current for both the things?